# API to put reviews in google reviews

Tags: google-api

Is there an API to put reviews in google (the ones that you see when you search in google for a certain place, busyness...)?

I am looking for it but can't find anyway so I am not sure there is one.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to automatically add reviews for places...?

Comment: If you own a business and want to allow posting reviews on your website that automatically get added to Google for example.

Comment: @AsheraH that is exactly what I want!